# Como verificar se o usuário está logado no VueJS + Laravel 5.5?

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.5

Estou acompanhando um curso de Laravel 5.5 + VueJS, e colocando em prática o que está sendo ensinado. Porém, o mesmo não aborda sobre autenticação no momento, e como estou estruturando todo o projeto para carregar seu conteúdo com VueJS, está ficando um pouco 'triste' o refresh de página no sistema de login.

Então, temporariamente, eu fiz uma pequena funções no método beforeCreate para enviar uma requisição. Porém, dessa forma, todas as requisições feitas pelo usuário, efetuam 2 requisições: Um para saber se está conectado e o outro do próprio usuário. Estive pensando na melhor maneira de solucionar isso, então, enxerguei a possibilidade de inserir um campo definitivo em todas as respostas de requisições com um booleano indicando se está ou não autenticado. Mas da mesma forma que a primeira, acredito ser um belíssimo POG.

Por isso pergunto, como verificar se o usuário está autenticado no VueJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nos sistemas que eu faço eu trabalho como se o front-end estivesse separado, e nesse caso, ao efetuar login eu retorno dados basicos do usuario incluindo um token,  salvando isso no localstorage. De uma olhada na documentação, laravel ja tem um esquema pronto.

Feito isso, em todo requisição que o usuario precisa estar logado eu envio esse token e caso o token for invalido o laravel vai me retornar um status http 401 (se nao me engano) me dizendo que o usuario nao esta logado, dessa forma eu trato como eu precisar.

Espero que eu tenha entendido certo a dúvida e se sim, que eu tenha conseguido clarear alguma coisa.